# Xamarin Erro CS0161 GetResponse<T>(string, string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this code, but i got a error : Error CS0161  'ApiCall.GetResponse(string, string, string)': not all code paths return a value

```
public class ApiCall
{
    static readonly string ApiUrl = "http://localhost:1762/api/{0}/{1}?{2}";

    public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(string controller, string method, string prm) where T : class
    {

        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(ApiUrl, controller, method, prm));
        var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return null;

        var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonResult);
            return rootobject;
   }
 }
}
```

Someone knows ?

Comment: That `return rootobject;` is indented, is that because in fact it is wrapped in an `if`?

Comment: Sidenote: `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` should be awaited.

Comment: You've got too many closing brackets. I suspect you're missing a starting bracket somewhere which makes the compiler thing you've got a bigger if-statement than you actually want.

Comment: @MageXy i cutted the code to past here...

Comment: @GSerg is out...its because i putted a try catch and i pasted the code, i didn´t fix , but its correct... the error is something else

Comment: Do you have a `return` in both  `try` and `catch` @MarceloCFernandes? Pretty useless to show code that is not the actual code.